# responsive HTML images using width and height values in image tag

Tags: javascript, html, size, screen-resolution, responsive-images

Currently my website is setup where the full image that is in it is loaded then automatically sized to fit the screen. This is done by setting image width to 100% in CSS. While it does work nicely, It doesn't seem to follow standards because I don't specify width and height in the image tag itself.

My idea now is to create multiple versions of the same webpage, where the only difference is the size of the image. Each image would have its own filename (like image1small.jpg, image1medium.jpg etc).

The problem is most people want to see the bigger picture right away but this doesn't go well with people with small screens since they have to scroll horizontally to see the whole thing.

I was thinking putting javascript at the top that redirects users who don't meet screen criteria to the page with the better sized image. Something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    if (screen.width < nnn){window.location.href="smallerpicture.htm";}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>some random text</p>
<img src="image.jpg" width=nnn height=yyy>
</body>
</html>
```

The thing is a page redirect will occur for people who do not meet the screen resolution requirements for the page. I'm not sure if this can qualify as a sneaky redirect to google.

Is this a good practice to use the code like I showed above to redirect users with incompatible screen size to the correct page? or should I take a different approach to display the correct sized image to the user?

And regardless of the answer anyone gives, I feel I need to specify the width and height attribute for the image tag and I want to stick to the HTML 4.01 strict standard so that the page will work for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

The first draft of the HTML 5 standard was designed to work for everyone - it basically documented "what browsers actually do", rather than what browsers *were supposed to do*.

The rationale behind specifying the width and height attributes is that it reserves the space on the page even before the image loads, preventing the need to re-flow the content when the image loads.

Choosing to specify the attributes, but then redirecting the page, will cause a worse re-render than using the % width without the attributes. So I think your concern is unfounded as your medicine is worse than the illness.

The desire to server different image sizes is one of the use cases for responsive images, so you can take a look at that as an option rather than reloading the page. There are several fallbacks that give you wide-ranging browser support.